# Let X be the average of a sample of 16 independent normal random variables with mean 0 and variance 1. Determine c such that P(|X| < c) = .5

Tags: statistics

Let $\overline{X}$  be the average of a sample of $16$ independent normal random variables with mean $0$ and variance $1$. Determine c such that
$P(| \overline{X} | < c) = .5$

I am having a lot of trouble with this question. I know it is related to chi-square but I don't know how to even start.

Comment: Why chi-square? Distribution of $\bar X$ is known, which should be enough to find $c$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X$ is distributed as $X\sim \mathcal N(0,1)$, then $\frac1n \sum\limits_{i=1}^{16} X_i=\overline X$ is distributed as $\overline X\sim \mathcal N\left( 0, \frac1{16}\right)$

Now we have to evaluate how $|\overline X|$ is distributed in terms of $\overline X$

$P(|\overline X| \leq c)=P(-c \leq \overline X \leq c)$

$=P(\overline X \leq c)-P(\overline X \leq -c)$

$=P(\overline X \leq c)-\left[ 1-P(\overline X \leq c) \right]$

$=2 \cdot P(\overline X \leq c)-1=2\cdot F_{\overline X}(c)-1$

At the next step we standardize $\overline X$ to be able to use the cdf of the standard normal distribution.

$2\cdot P(\overline X \leq c)-1=2\cdot \Phi\left(\frac{c-0}{\sqrt{\frac1{16}}} \right)-1=2\cdot \Phi\left(4c \right)-1=0.5$

$2\cdot \Phi\left(4c \right)=1.5$

$\Phi\left(4c \right)=0.75$

$4c=\Phi^{-1}\left(0.75\right)$

$\Phi^{-1}\left(p\right)$ is the inverse function of $\Phi\left(z\right)$

$4c=0.674\Rightarrow c=0.1685$

Comment: I am kind of lost on the step where we standardize X. Everything before that makes sense.

Comment: @GeorgeHarrison Let $\overline X \sim \mathcal N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, then $Z=\frac{\overline X-\mu}{\sigma}\sim N(0,1)$. In your exercise $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=\sqrt{\frac1{16}}=\frac14$.

Comment: I am not getting where you are getting the mean is 0 and the standard deviation is 0.25.

Comment: In your example $P(\overline X\leq c)$ is the same as $P(Z\leq 4c)$ due standardizing.

Comment: @GeorgeHarrison The expected value of the mean of n  variables is the mean  of the expected values. And for $n$ i.i.d random variables we have $Var\left (\frac1n \sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i \right)=\frac1{n^2}\cdot Var\left (\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i \right)=Var\left (\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i \right)$ $=\frac1{n^2}\cdot\left(Var(X_1)+Var(X_2)+\ldots+Var(X_n)\right)$. Since the $X_i$´s has the same variance we get: $=\frac1{n^2}\cdot n\cdot Var(X_1)=\frac1n\cdot \sigma^2$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, but I am still a bit lost. I am understanding that we get 2P(X<c) - 1, but what exactly happens after that. where does the 1/16 come from?

Comment: @GeorgeHarrison This comes from what I´ve written at the beginning and tried to explain in my previous comment. The variance of the mean of n variables is equal to the the variance of a single variable ($\sigma^2$) divided by $n$ which is $\frac{\sigma^2}{n}=\frac1{16}$. To get the standard deviation we take the square root, which is $\sigma=\frac14$. Have a look to this [link](https://newonlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/167/). Here it is explained how the variance of $\overline X$ is derived. It is more or less the same what I´ve written, but maybe its more comprehensible for you.

Comment: @GeorgeHarrison I you have no further question you´re supposed to accept an answer. Just click on the checkmark ($\color{limegreen}{\checkmark}$).

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**- The sum of independent normal variables also follows the normal distribution with

$$N(\sum_{i=1}^n {\mu_i},\sum_{i=1}^n {\sigma_i^2})$$

Also, if a random variable $X$ has mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, then the random variable $Y=kX$ (where $k$ is a constant) has mean $k\mu$ and variance $k^2\sigma^2$